# AttributeError: type object 'typing.re' has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split

I try to scam URL link form google. Users can input any search then they can take a URL link. but here is the main problem is this split function can't work. I can't fix it. So please help me
[[Suppose: Any user can input "all useless website" that time google can showing us a result. User can take only URL link.]]

```
from typing import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_input = input('Enter value for search : ')
print('Please Wait')
page_source = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + user_input)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
print(soup.title.string)
print(soup.title.parent.name)

all_links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in all_links:
    link_google = re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", ""))
    print(link_google.find["a"])
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update to make your code work:

1. `import re` correctly
2. fix this line from `all_links = soup.find_all('a')` to `all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)`
3. Take the link and clean it up like you did before (`re.split()` works perfectly but it returns a list) and add that link to a list (**unpack the list**) or print it

### Here is the code updated to make it work

```
# issue 1
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_input = input('Enter value for search : ')
print('Please Wait')
page_source = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + user_input)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.title)
print(soup.title.string)
print(soup.title.parent.name)

# issue 2
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)


for link in all_links:
    link_from_google = re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", ""))
    # issue 3
    print(link_from_google[0])
```

```
>>> {returns all the http links}
```

#### One liner list comprehension for fun

```
google_links = [re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", ""))[0] for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

```
>>> {returns all the http links}
```

Comment: can I talk with you? I need more help.

Comment: I need your help. if you free and see my comment then please contact on mail or skype..my mail address is sakibhasan1420@gmail.com and skype name is "Sakib Hasan" or the same mail in skype id.

Comment: Just post more questions on stack overflow and you can get the community’s support that way!

Comment: can you upvote/accept my answer so it may help others

Answer (score 2):

You're importing `re` from the wrong place. You need to use it via `import re`, as follows:

```
import re
...
    link_google = re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", ""))
```